# Specify what type of queue is that

Tags: queue, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I'm very new to messaging system, and I was trying to find my answer on http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/, and I'm pretty sure it should be over there, but so far I got little bit confused with all bindings, queues, exchanges.

So I'm looking an answer for the question how to specify what type of "queue" (sorry if i have to use other word for this) is it. On producer side. To be more clear I'll give you an example:

[image]

So I want my consumer to subscribe to one "queue" and than once it receives it perform some operation based on what's inside this queue. Lets say if message contains a picture than do something, if it is a text, than do something else.

I was thinking my producer should add something like `type:foo` to the payload, and than consumer will look for this `type`. But I hope there is a better solution for this. Something like add a header to the queue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your consumer have to do different tasks for different types of message, then it would be better to create one distinct consumer per task.

That way, you can easily create one queue for each type of message and make each consumer consume messages from the right queue.

Your producer can send the message to the correct queue either directly or by using RabbitMQ routing.

Take a look at the "Routing" tutorial on the RabbitMQ website, it seems to match your use-case : http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html